# Renderizar Iframe google Maps com AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, iframe, angularjs-directives

Eu estou montando uma diretiva para renderizar um iframe do google maps dentro da minha app.

E consegui fazer desta forma:

```
<google-iframe location="item.Location"></google-iframe>
```

diretiva.js

```
function googleIframe() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            location: '='
        },
        template: '<iframe src="%url%" height="250" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" alt="{{location.url}}"></iframe>',
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        var url = [
            'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?',
            'key=AIzaSyCBOhDJn9LAUiqONa-y-f1l2JmFEoadkaQ',
            '&q=', scope.location.lat, ',', scope.location.lng,
            '&zoom=', scope.location.zoom
        ];
        element[0].outerHTML = element[0].outerHTML.replace('%url%', url.join(""));
    }
```

Porém, o que eu gostaria de verdade, é renderizar a url correta em conjunto com a diretiva, ao invés de substituir a url após a renderização da diretiva.

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Fora do asunto, mas da uma olhada em Leaflet.js
Realmente muito fácil (bem mas que a API Google) e permite usar no mesmo tempo as mapas de Google, Bing, Yandex, OSM etc... com camada, pop-up etc...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas realmente preciso usar o serviço do google.

Comment: Angular Google Maps é um plugin com angularJS directives prontas. Link: https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Comment: Eu conheço... Mas não quero usar, muita coisa para fazer só isto aí.

Comment: Esta pergunta do SO em inglês responde sua dúvida: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Comment: Uma alternativa de uso de um plugin já pronto, como também mencionado pelo @OnoSendai seria este: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps eu uso e acho excelente